# boost spirit grammar error - "no type named ‘size’ in ‘struct boost::spirit::unused_type’"

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit-qi

Could please help me with diagnosing the following error. I have a simple grammar:

```
struct json_start_elem_grammar_object : qi::grammar<StreamIterator,
                                                  void(const CharType*, CharType),
                                                  ascii::space_type>
{
  json_start_elem_grammar_object() : json_start_elem_grammar_object::base_type(start_elem, "start_elem")
  {
    start_elem =  qi::lit('"') > qi::lit(qi::_1) > qi::lit('"') > qi::lit(':') >
                  qi::lit(qi::_2) > -qi::lit('\n');
  }

  qi::rule<StreamIterator, void(const CharType*, CharType), ascii::space_type>  start_elem;
};
```

when making an instance of this grammar I get an error:

```
/usr/include/boost/spirit/home/qi/nonterminal/rule.hpp:220:19:   required from ‘boost::spirit::qi::rule<Iterator, T1, T2, T3, T4>& boost::spirit::qi::rule<Iterator, T1, T2, T3, T4>::operator=(const Expr&) [with Expr = boost::proto::exprns_::expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::greater, boost::proto::argsns_::list2<const boost::proto::exprns_::expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::greater, boost::proto::argsns_::list2<const boost::proto::exprns_::expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::greater, boost::proto::argsns_::list2<const boost::proto::exprns_::expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::greater, boost::proto::argsns_::list2<const boost::proto::exprns_::expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::greater, boost::proto::argsns_::list2<const boost::proto::exprns_::expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::terminal, boost::proto::argsns_::term<boost::spirit::terminal_ex<boost::spirit::tag::lit, boost::fusion::vector1<char> > >, 0l>&, const boost::proto::exprns_::expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::terminal, boost::proto::argsns_::term<boost::spirit::lazy_terminal<boost::spirit::tag::lit, boost::phoenix::actor<boost::phoenix::composite<boost::phoenix::detail::function_eval<1>, boost::fusion::vector<boost::phoenix::value<boost::spirit::terminal<boost::spirit::tag::lit> >, boost::spirit::argument<0>, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_> > >, 1> >, 0l>&>, 2l>&, const boost::proto::exprns_::expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::terminal, boost::proto::argsns_::term<boost::spirit::terminal_ex<boost::spirit::tag::lit, boost::fusion::vector1<char> > >, 0l>&>, 2l>&, const boost::proto::exprns_::expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::terminal, boost::proto::argsns_::term<boost::spirit::terminal_ex<boost::spirit::tag::lit, boost::fusion::vector1<char> > >, 0l>&>, 2l>&, const boost::proto::exprns_::expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::terminal, boost::proto::argsns_::term<boost::spirit::lazy_terminal<boost::spirit::tag::lit, boost::phoenix::actor<boost::phoenix::composite<boost::phoenix::detail::function_eval<1>, boost::fusion::vector<boost::phoenix::value<boost::spirit::terminal<boost::spirit::tag::lit> >, boost::spirit::argument<1>, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_> > >, 1> >, 0l>&>, 2l>&, const boost::proto::exprns_::expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::negate, boost::proto::argsns_::list1<const boost::proto::exprns_::expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::terminal, boost::proto::argsns_::term<boost::spirit::terminal_ex<boost::spirit::tag::lit, boost::fusion::vector1<char> > >, 0l>&>, 1l>&>, 2l>; Iterator = boost::spirit::basic_istream_iterator<char>; T1 = void(const char*, char); T2 = boost::proto::exprns_::expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::terminal, boost::proto::argsns_::term<boost::spirit::tag::char_code<boost::spirit::tag::space, boost::spirit::char_encoding::ascii> >, 0l>; T3 = boost::spirit::unused_type; T4 = boost::spirit::unused_type]’
/home/marcin/workspace/json_archive/basic_json_grammar.hpp:149:18:   required from ‘boost::archive::basic_json_grammar<CharType>::json_start_elem_grammar_object::json_start_elem_grammar_object() [with CharType = char]’
/home/marcin/workspace/json_archive/basic_json_grammar.hpp:194:50:   required from ‘boost::archive::basic_json_grammar<CharType>::basic_json_grammar() [with CharType = char]’
/home/marcin/workspace/json_archive/json_iarchive_impl.ipp:141:85:   required from ‘boost::archive::json_iarchive_impl<Archive>::json_iarchive_impl(std::istream&, unsigned int) [with Archive = boost::archive::naked_json_iarchive; std::istream = std::basic_istream<char>]’
/home/marcin/workspace/json_archive/json_iarchive.hpp:102:68:   required from here
/usr/include/boost/fusion/sequence/intrinsic/size.hpp:33:20: error: no type named ‘size’ in ‘struct boost::spirit::unused_type’
         struct unsegmented_size : Sequence::size {};
```

where

```
using CharType = char;
using StreamIterator = spirit::basic_istream_iterator<CharType>;
```

After few days of working with boost.serialization & boost.spirit compilation errors I'm totally brain-dead and seem to be stuck on this one :/

The usage of this grammar (slightly simplified) is:

```
json_start_elem_grammar_object start_elem_parser_object;
using invoker = _details::invoke_grammar<CharType, decltype(start_elem_parser_object(name, preamble))>;

invoker::apply( is,
              start_elem_parser_object(name, preamble),
              "Invalid object element in archive");
```

where

```
decltype(is) = IStream& 
decltype(name) = const CharType* 
decltype(preamble) = CharType 


template<typename CharType, typename Expr>
struct invoke_grammar<CharType, Expr> {
 using IStream = std::basic_istream<CharType>;
 using StreamIterator = spirit::basic_istream_iterator<CharType>;

 static void apply(IStream & is, Expr const& grammar, const CharType* errMsg)
 {
   boost::io::ios_flags_saver ifs(is);
   is.unsetf (std::ios::skipws);

   StreamIterator it_end;
   StreamIterator it_beg (is);

   if (!qi::phrase_parse(it_beg, it_end,
                        grammar,
                        ascii::space))
   {
     boost::serialization::throw_exception(
       archive_exception(archive_exception::invalid_signature, errMsg)
     );
   }
 }
};
```

Comment: We need usage of this grammar.

Comment: inherited attributes are `qi::_r1`, `qi::_r2` etc. (not `_1`,`_2`). Also, have a look at `qi::symbols<>` to avoid the use of inherited attributes here. If you want to code a grammar _control-freak-style_ I think you'd be better off rolling it without Spirit.

Comment: @ ForEveR Ive added the usage describtion to the question

Comment: @sehe qi::_rX and qi::X produce the same compilation error in this exact case. When choosing the placeholders I consulted the http://boost-spirit.com/home/2010/03/03/the-anatomy-of-semantic-actions-in-qi/ from which I understand that _1 and _2 are ok in the context of a whole parser - please correct me if I'm wrong. I do not want to use symbols because the name and preamble are known late, at the runtime and it's easier to pass them as inherited attributes to the parser. Thanks

Comment: @Marcin the placeholders are "ok", but they don't mean the same thing (this actually makes quite a bit of sense, if you think about it)

Comment: Why don't you make it a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)? (I mean, why make your helpers solve a jig-saw puzzle before even being able to reproduce your question?). You could have had the answer 8 hours earlier :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like I commented, you need to use `qi::_r1` and `qi::_r2`, the placeholders for [*inherited attributes*](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/parser_concepts/nonterminal.html#spirit.qi.reference.parser_concepts.nonterminal._code__phrase_role__identifier___r1__phrase___code_______code__phrase_role__identifier__r10__phrase___code_)<sup>[1]</sup>.

For the rest I can assume things (as your code is incomplete and slightly unclear to me due to a non-standard approach):

- you probably want `ascii::blank_type` as the skipper, since otherwise `lit('\n')` would never match (unless with `no_skip[]` or `lexeme[]`).
- you have to take care to call the parser with an actual `CharType const*`, not a `CharType const (&)[]`. The latter happens if you call it with e.g. `parser("name", 'a')`. Instead, either

  - introduce a temporary variable
  - a cast
  - implicitely decay using e.g. `+"name"`

I've made up an example and it succeeds, see it **[Live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9821f9d05a44f5a3)**

Full code:

```
#define BOOST_SPIRIT_USE_PHOENIX_V3
#include <boost/fusion/adapted.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>

namespace qi    = boost::spirit::qi;
namespace ascii = boost::spirit::ascii;

template <typename StreamIterator, typename CharType=char>
struct json_start_elem_grammar_object : qi::grammar<StreamIterator,
    void(const CharType*, CharType),
    ascii::blank_type>
{
    json_start_elem_grammar_object() : json_start_elem_grammar_object::base_type(start_elem, "start_elem")
    {
        using namespace qi;
        _r1_type _name;     // prefer descriptive names
        _r2_type _preamble;

        start_elem = 
            '"' > lit(_name) > '"' > 
            ':' > lit(_preamble) > 
            -lit('\n')
            ;
    }

    qi::rule<StreamIterator, void(const CharType*, CharType), ascii::blank_type>  start_elem;
};

bool doParse(const std::string& input)
{
    typedef std::string::const_iterator It;
    auto f(begin(input)), l(end(input));

    json_start_elem_grammar_object<It> p;

    try
    {
        bool ok = qi::phrase_parse(f, l, p(+"lol", 'q'), ascii::blank);
        if (ok)   
        {
            std::cout << "parse success\n";
        }
        else      std::cerr << "parse failed: '" << std::string(f,l) << "'\n";

        if (f!=l) std::cerr << "trailing unparsed: '" << std::string(f,l) << "'\n";
        return ok;
    } catch(const qi::expectation_failure<It>& e)
    {
        std::string frag(e.first, e.last);
        std::cerr << e.what() << "'" << frag << "'\n";
    }

    return false;
}

int main()
{
    bool ok = doParse("\"lol\" : q\n");
    return ok? 0 : 255;
}
```

---

<sup>[1]</sup> See also

- documentation for [non-terminals](http://boost-spirit.com/home/articles/attribute_handling/the-magical-power-of-attributes-in-spirit-directives-and-non-terminals/)
- the [mini-xml example from the tutorial](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/tutorials/mini_xml___asts_.html#spirit.qi.tutorials.mini_xml___asts_.inherited_attribute)

Comment: Thank you very much for help. The specific error I experienced was a result of boost bug https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/8774. Puting the "BOOST_RESULT_OF_USE_TR1" define fixed the compilation error. I'm acceptiong your anwser since you pointed out some other errors I made. Sorry for making you "foretell" the anwser. I could not produce a 100% acurate SSCCE (in a reasonable time) because of the number of interactions present. I used the boost.spirit in to add some functionality to boost.serialization framework. It was hard to find the minimal example.

Comment: I have a feeling that `BOOST_RESULT_OF_USE_DECLTYPE` might automatically be defined for recent compilers, however PhoenixV2 doesn't work with it (?). Instead of "going back in time" (using TR1 result-of protocol) consider going _with the times_ (like my sample shows) and defining `BOOST_SPIRIT_USE_PHOENIX_V3` instead. I highly suspect that will work too.

Comment: Oh, and also: the specific error you got was **not** because of that bug: it was because of using `_1` instead of `_r1` (see http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/854d1f1cca5b92c4)

Comment: Yes, I had more then one error in my code. I've probably mistook one error with another. Thanks again. As you guessed I'm using Spirit V2 - this version is a requirement for the product I'm working on. Cheers!

Comment: Please read more closely. `BOOST_SPIRIT_USE_PHOENIX_V3` is very much Spirit V2. In fact, in my experience PhoenixV2 support in SpiritV2 is more of a legacy thing (many many errors have been fixed in PhoenixV3 and I've never seen anything break in Spirit due to using PhoenixV3)

Comment: OK, I'll give it a go when I'll have time budget. Thank you for your insight. It's the first time I'm using spirit and I'm strongly impressed. It's a pitty I currently do not have more time to dwell into it.